# problem to call parent window function from child window with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I open a window like this :

```
var impressionWindow = window.open('index.php?module=Products&src_module=Oneidsousjob&src_field=sousjob_article&src_record=&view=Popup&triggerEventName=postSelection', 'Popup', 'scrollbars=1,resizable=1,height=560,width=770');
```

and i try to call a function in the parent window with this code:

```
window.opener.postSelection();
```

But the child window said :
Uncaught TypeError: window.opener.postSelection is not a function

i don't know why i try other way like theses:

```
window.parent.postSelection();
```

result is the same postSelection is not a function
Or with an event like this:

```
window.parent.$(window.parent.document).trigger('postSelection');
```

with this nothing happen...

Bref i need some help and many thanks by advance...

Comment: Is the `postSelection()` function defined at root level of the parent page?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes:
like this:
`$.Class('Planification_List_Js', {},
    {
postSelection: function (){
alert();
}
}`

Comment: That's not at the root level. That's in the scope of the object within `$.Class()`. That's why your code doesn't work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i don't know what i must doing? sorry, i don't understand.